# cv::Exception at memory location 0x0000000296AFDAD0 in visual studio

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to get eigenvalues from an image matrix. I tried with a streaming video and did not get an error. When I tried to find eigenvalues of a stored  image I get `cv::Exception at memory location 0x0000000296AFDAD0 error.`

```
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
void calceigen(Mat covarm){
Mat eigenvalues;
Mat eigenvectors;
eigen(covarm, eigenvalues, eigenvectors);
cout << eigenvalues;
cout << eigenvectors;
}

void covard(Mat g)
{
Mat covarm;
Mat b;
calcCovarMatrix(g, covarm, b, CV_COVAR_COLS, CV_64F);
calceigen(covarm);

}


int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{ 



cv::Mat image = cv::imread("C:/Users/DellPc/Desktop/images1.jpg");
//setup image files used in the capture process
Mat grayscaleFrame;
Mat graysc;







    //convert captured image to gray scale and equalize
    //cvtColor(image, grayscaleFrame, CV_BGR2GRAY);


    //resize(grayscaleFrame, graysc, Size(16, 16), 0, 0, INTER_LANCZOS4);

    int rows = image.rows;
    int cols = image.cols;
    cv::Size s = image.size();
    rows = s.height;
    cols = s.width;
    cout << rows << endl;
    cout << cols << endl;

    covard(image);
    //find faces and store them in the vector array
    imshow("small", image);
    waitKey(33);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it write something to the console window? What about the image size?

Comment: ya im getting output on console window. i tried to reduce the image to 16x16. but the i got some linker error. and then i gave the image directly. image sixe is 256x256.

Comment: Did you use the opencv libs/dlls correctly? Make sure you link the .lib files of the same configuration (release vs Debug) and the same platform (x86 vs x64) of your build

Comment: yes i have added all libraries and additional dependencies and also it is x64 platform in debug mode

Comment: some memory exception handling is need i think. but i don't know exactly about it.

Comment: your code works properly, which opencv version do you use?

Comment: I'm using opencv version 2.4.10 and visual studio 2013.